# CUDA 9 unsupported error with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I've recently updated my VS 2017 and now I cannot even build a default CUDA project (the one with the vector addition).

I suspect that this is due to the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1189   #error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! 
 Only the versions 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 are supported! ver2    
c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing 
toolkit\cuda\v9.0\include\crt\host_config.h 133
```

The other errors are irrelevant and will disappear once I fix this one. Note, that I am able to build and run simpleCUFFT from CUDA samples.

Before the update I was able to build the default CUDA project but I was not able to build the CUDA Sample project. I've updated my VS2017 using VS installer and installed CUDA SDK 10.0.15063.0. Attached is the screenshot[image: screenshot] with the installed components.

Please let me know if any additional information is required. I am aware of the [following](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1022648/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-unsupported-visual-studio-version-error/) topic and since I am using the latest CUDA toolkit, I don't need to make changes in host_config.h.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Edit:
My VS version (as displayed in VS installer) is 15.5.0
My nvcc version is release 9.0, V9.0.176

Edit2: I've tryied to change host_config.h line 133 to:

```
  #if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1912
```

This error does not show up anymore, however, a bunch of errors "expression must have a constant value" show up in the file type_trails. I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Microsoft have already released at least one update of VS2017 which broke CUDA 9. You might be a victim of another. When did you download and install both CUDA and VS and what exact version do both report?

Comment: Thanks, I've made an edit to my post

Comment: Can someone who is using VS2017 and CUDA post there versions of both please

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some painful time, I was able to solve the problem. Here is the answer for those who have a similar problem:

1) Make sure that you have VC++ 2015.3 v140 toolset (can be installed either from web or Visual Studio installer)

2) In the project properties (general) -> Platform toolset choose Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Edit (5/21/2018): I've just updated Visual studio 2017 to the latest version 15.7.1. From now on, I can choose VS 2017 v141 toolset and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah that is a good approach, however if you use features that are only available in toolset v141 and need CUDA this won't help much.

Comment: This works, but to compile the 162 projects in the sample solution, you need to use a 'replace in files' tool to replace <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset> with <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset> in *.vcxproj in c:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v9.1\

Comment: Note that if you use cmake you can specify -T v140 to select the right platform toolkit.

Comment: There is a way to change this setting for all projects (there are 162) in the solution quickly and from the UI. Simply select multiple projects at once, then right click project properties, and follow instructions for above answer. You can select all the projects at once by: 1) ctrl-A  2) then deselect all non-projects ( the solution and the folders).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using CUDA 9.2 and VS 2017 (Version 15.7.5). Simply Modifying host_config.h (usually under *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.*\include\crt, can be found in the VS output from build*) works for me.

Change the line

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1913
```

to

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1600 || _MSC_VER > 1914
```

or something similar, based on the version of cl.exe

Comment: Hi, I was using CUDA 9.0 and it didn't work. It might work with CUDA 9.2. I will check it later and confirm

Comment: Did you change only this, or something else as well. I am asking because I use CUDA 9.2. and it still does not work.

Comment: Only this. I think you can safely remove the second part "|| _MSC_VER > 1914", because vs 2017 is frequently getting updated. Right now _MSC_VER should already be 1915

Answer (score 2):

In VS update 15.4.3 Microsoft updated version number of their CL compiler to 14.12
(https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.4.4)

That's why CUDA 9.0.176 refuse to compile.
Today NVIDIA updated CUDA to 9.1.85, so just update
just update CUDA to 9.1 
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: This no longer works cause now there is VS 15.5.4 which introduces CL 19.12
Nvidia needs to release another update ASAP

Comment: With the latest CUDA toolkit (9.1.85) and latest Visual Studio 17 version, 15.6.5 still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that's reading this question, update in CUDA 10. It works right out of the box. No need to install previous compiler tool-sets and the like mentioned in other answers. Simply download CUDA 10, install it and uninstall previous CUDA versions. Then make a new CUDA 10 project and place your code. It will work.

If you're getting errors, don't forget to set `compute_xx,sm_xx` appropriately, in Project Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation.

Comment: what about visual studio 2019?