# CUDA 9.1 Visual Studio 2017 Preview compilation error

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2017

Just installed latest Visual Studio 2017 Preview 15.6 and CUDA Toolkit 9.1
Created new CUDA demo project and tried to compile, but got bunch of errors, one of them:

```
cannot open source file "stddef.h"    
cannot open source file "stdio.h"    
unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 are supported
```

Did anyone try to work with CUDA 9.1 in VS 2017 Preview?

Comment: Are those includes coming from your code?

Comment: The latest CUDA Toolkit 9.1 is not officially supporting VS 2017 versions beyond 1911 which is v15.4.x   VS 2017 v1912 and beyond  (v15.5.x and higher) are not officially supported by the latest CUDA 9.1 toolkit.

Comment: If you want to use CUDA 9 or 9.1 with VS2017, and you have an unsupported version of VS2017 already installed (or upgraded to) such as 1912 or later, one possible approach would be to install the VS2015 toolchain within VS2017 as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645436/cuda-9-unsupported-error-with-vs-2017).   Another possibility may be to try and download a previous (v15.4.x) version of VS2017.  it may still be possible to download that from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017).

Comment: Thanks Robert, your help is appreciated. Also found some info here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027299/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-failed-to-support-the-latest-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5

Comment: As a further update, it appears that Microsoft my have just released a v15.5.2 version of VS2017 which is working with CUDA 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per advises from Robert and [NVidia DevTalk forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027299/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-failed-to-support-the-latest-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5) in order to compile project I need to:

1. Install Visual Studio 2017.4 from here
   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017
2. Reinstall CUDA

or

1. Add Visual Stodio 2015 Toolset to existing VS 2017 installation
2. Reinstall CUDA
3. Change project properties to use older toolset

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get CUDA 9.1.85 to build with VS 2017 15.4.

I first uninstalled all previous VS instances and then reinstalled VS2017, making sure to go to "individual Components" and selecting VS 2015 Toolset.

I then used the Step A suggestion from @oregonduckman [in this post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1033111/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-1-cannot-install-due-to-failed-visual-studio-integration/post/5259359/#5259359) and used the standard VGA driver for my display adapter (video card).

I then killed every NVIDIA process and manually deleted every NVIDIA folder on my machine.

Finally, I installed CUDA 9.1.85 including the VS Integrations which also reinstalled my display adapter driver that I had manually removed. I was then able to build all of the CUDA samples.

I suspect that the issue lays with either the VS Toolset is unsupported by CUDA 9.1 or there was an incompatibility between VS and my NVIDIA driver somehow. 
Btw, I am running Windows 10 Pro with a GTX 780 card.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following to fix the problem on VS 2017 Enterprise:

1. Open VS 2017--> Tools --> Get Tools and Features --> Add Visual Studio 2015 (v140) Toolset and Windows SDK Version 10.0.15063.0
2. Reinstall CUDA
3. Right click on the project --> Properties --> Configuration Properties --> General --> Set target platform version to 10.0.15063.0 and set platform toolset to Visual Studio 2015 (v140)