# Cannot install CUDA Toolkit 9.1.85 on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA Toolkit 9.1.85 on my machine. With the first attempt, all seems working until I tried to compile OpenCV 3.4.1 with CUDA support on Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6. I checked on the internet and I found a lot [info](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030799/cuda-9-1-on-visual-studio-2017-15-6/) about the error. On the second attempt, I followed what suggested [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027209/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-0-does-not-work-with-the-latest-vs-2017-update/post/5228921/#5228921) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645436/cuda-9-unsupported-error-with-vs-2017), but I cannot successfully install CUDA.

Launching CUDA installation with the following command:

```
setup.exe -log:"D:\logcuda" -loglevel:6
```

And looking into the log file, I find that

```
ERROR: [NVI2.NVInstaller] 2064@CNVInstaller::InternalPerformInstall : Package "visual_studio_integration_9.1" failed with error: Exception {0x80004005 - Unspecified error.; File: PerformInstall.cpp; Line: 4029; Phase failure}.
```

If I try to install CUDA without Visual Studio Integration, I can successfully install CUDA (not tried to compile OpenCV).

Before the second attempt, I removed all NVIDIA components (driver and so on), used DDU, removed Visual Studio with all components (launched also InstallCleanup.exe), run CCleaner.

Now I am with Visual Studio 2017 15.4.5 and only VC++ 2015.3 140 (141 is not installed), NVIDIA 397.31, but still getting the same error. With the first attempt, I install successfully CUDA with Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6 VC++ 2017 v141 with Visual Studio Integration.

Can someone point me in the right way? I cannot figure out fix it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Same problem. I'm almost hopeless...

Comment: There are a few threads in NVIDIA forum about this problem. But none gets explained by NVIDIA. The error happens at File: `PerformInstall.cpp`; Line: `4029`. But we can't figure out what's wrong with that line.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I linked one of them here. Seems that something remains and it is not fully removed (I am refering to Visual Studio installation) but I do not know where to find it. Now I am without Visual Studio and CUDA. I am waiting for CUDA 9.2, but today Microsoft release Visual Studio 15.7. I hope that all will work in right the way.

Comment: @chaosink , can you try if my solution works for you? Maybe I forgot something in the description.

Answer (score 3):

Following [this suggestion](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1033111/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-1-cannot-install-due-to-failed-visual-studio-integration/post/5260980/#5260980) , here's how I installed CUDA 9.2 for Visual Studio 2017 15.6.7:

1. Current Visual Studio 2017 version is 15.7.3, so I had to [download an earlier version from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017).
2. Unzip CUDA installer like an archive into a directory, say `C:\cuda_9.2.88_win10\`
3. Install CUDA without Visual Studio Integration (you need to choose Custom instead of Express installation)
4. Copy `C:\cuda_9.2.88_win10\CUDAVisualStudioIntegration\extras\visual_studio_integration\MSBuildExtensions` to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations` .
5. Copy `C:\cuda_9.2.88_win10\CUDAVisualStudioIntegration\extras\visual_studio_integration\CudaProjectVsWizards`
   to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\CUDA`
6. Run as administrator: `devenv /setup` from directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE`
7. Install all the .msi from `C:\cuda_9.2.88_win10\CUDAVisualStudioIntegration`